# Storing value of form input, because onsubmit form will be removed? Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, global-variables, storing-data

I'm having an issue where i'm trying to store the value of a form input so I can call it later, but on submit, the form is removed. The process of what I am trying to achieve is that once the form is removed on submit, it will populate a div with the form input value to deliver a message.

I have two functions:

The first function validates the input fields on window.onload, and has the input value

The second function processes the data to provide results onsubmit

these are the variables that are stored in the function performing the validation:

```
var fnamez = document.getElementById("last_name_id").value;
var ftext = document.createTextNode(fnamez);
```

this is the function that is performed on submit

```
function processForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();

if (q1_valid == true && q2_valid == true && q3_valid == true && q4_valid == true && q5_valid == true) {
    var badge = document.getElementById("badge");
    badge.setAttribute('class', 'badge');

    var form_div = document.getElementById('form');
    // remove all child nodes
    while (form_div.hasChildNodes()) {
        form_div.removeChild(form_div.lastChild);
    }

    var congrats = document.createTextNode('congratulations!');
    badge.appendChild(congrats);

    // issue occurs here; thinking its a result of the removal of form
    var zfname = document.getElementById('first_name_id').value;
    var fnametext = document.createTextNode(zfname);
    badge.appendChild(fnametext);


}
```

badge is the name of the variable that locates the div id = badge

Thank you in advance!

Comment: would it be possible to save the input values in a global variable, so that it can be called in processform function?

Comment: Please be so kind and indent your code properly.

Comment: Not really. Indenting code means lining up lines and braces consistently and no that's not a minor problem that's beside the point. ;)

Comment: lol well @tomalak whats your perspective on my question, is it possible to input values outside of the function in an array or global variable?

Comment: My perspective on your question is two-fold. **a)** If you indent all your code like this (or not at all) then you have bigger problems than global variables. Improperly formatted code is not only a source of bugs, it also is an imposition for other people that read your code. That's especially relevant when you want other people to help you. **b)** You should set up an example on jsFiddle. Your question does not contain enough code to outline your issue. For starters, why would anyone want to validate a form on *load*? Where are which variables defined? It's all very obscure.

Comment: @Tomalak I do understand that indenting is very important and i'll try again to make it better, im sorry im still new to programming. here is my js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iplayjumanji2/V374s/3/

Comment: The single, most import programming advice that springs to my mind when I see your code: Stop copy-and-pasting! Whenever you copy a block of code and re-use it with minimal or no changes, you're doing it wrong. There is so much almost-but-not-quite duplication in your code it's hard to spot the places where actual stuff happens. Write re-usable functions instead of repeating yourself. That being said yes you could use global variables, but I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: @tomalak i figured it out, all i had to do was to append the childs with the input values before I removed the form. And your absolutely right about using functions, instead of copying and pasting code. I'm just still very new to programing, and this is the first time I use DOM scripting. I'll try to make my code more elegant.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a version of your validation routine that uses a lot less code duplication and some advanced techniques that you might find interesting to explore or build upon. Take the time to look into it, set some breakpoints and find out how it works. http://jsfiddle.net/V374s/5/